# Can I get all cookies of a specific domain as ';'-separated string?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, chromium

Can I somehow list all currently storied cookies for a domain as string?

```
cookie1=value1;cookie2=value2;cookie3=value3
```

is what I have in mind. Is there any way to do it from the console, or maybe there's a built-in UI command for this that I missed?

Comment: Use document.cookie

Comment: Really? That easy? Thanks!

Comment: Beware that that will not return `HTTPOnly` cookies.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Use just document.cookie!

This variable stores what you need